# How can I use url in python

Tags: python, url, src

I'm using BeautifulSoup and Selenium to crawl imgs.

Some img src has '.jpg' and some are not.

This is my codes.

```py
book_img = soup.find_all('em', {'class': 'imgBdr'})
img_url = book_img[0].find('img')['src']

if '.jpg' in str(img_url):
 img = img_url
else:
 img = img_url + '.jpg'

img_name = book_img[0].find('img')['alt']
urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, "folder/" + img_name + '.jpg)
```

But error occurs like this
`urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found`

How can I crawl imgs?

Comment: You should print out the URL and see if it is correct and complete.

Comment: for one, if the image URL is missing `'.jpg'`, you probably want to add `'.jpg'` and not `'jpg'`

Comment: Some url like 'http://image.yes24.com/goods/58397337/800x0' this and others are like 'http://image.yes24.com/momo/TopCate1774/MidCate003/177325213.jpg' this

Comment: It's a typing error. modified it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple possible reasons that you code finds a 404.

Consider the possibility that there are more file types for images than .jpg

What if it was a `.png`? You are currently appending `.jpg` to anything that might not be a jpg.

`tinyfrog.png` would become --> `tinyfrog.png.jpg`

Try using `img_url` as the first parameter of `urllib.request.urlretrieve`

```
urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, "folder/" + img_name + img_url.split('.')[-1])
```

Note: `img_url.split('.')[-1]` is assuming there is a file ext. You can easily modify this for file that doesn't have an explict file extension.

Comment: Most of img src is like this "image.yes24.com/goods/58397337/800x0" without ```.jpg```. And appending ```.jpg``` has not occur error. But some src is like this "image.yes24.com/momo/TopCate1774/MidCate003/177325213.jpg" with ```.jpg```. When src like that happen it occur error.